Ubuntu PC keeps on freezing
I use Docker to run UISP on my PC, but every few hours the PC freezes up and I have to manually reboot it by holding down the power button. I've done a fresh install of Ubuntu and updated everything via sudo apt-get update, but I had no luck. Attached is a photo of the screen when the PC freezes up.

